# ShowDialog using children is deprecated how to use it the other way?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use showDialog in the following manner

```
showDialog(context: context,child:new Text("Hello Dialgo"));
```

The above works fine however it states that `child` parameter has been deprecated and the alternative way is to :

> 'Instead of using the "child" argument, return the child from a
>   closure '
>       'provided to the "builder" argument. This will ensure that the BuildContext '
>       'is appropriate for widgets built in the dialog.'

I am not sure what that means. Any simple example here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change it it

```
showDialog(
   context: context,
   builder: (_) => new Text("Hello Dialgo")
);
```

If you need the context from within the dialog change `builder: (_) =>` to `builder: (BuildContext context) =>`

**Because the Builder is a function handler, we need to create a function which accepts a single argument (BuildContext) and returns a Widget.**

Syntax can either be:

```
(BuildContext context) => new Text('...');
```

or

```
(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text('...')
}
```

They are equivalent, though the second one can have more than one line

See an example here: https://github.com/aqwert/flutter_auth_starter/blob/master/lib/core/dialogs/showError_dialog.dart

Comment: could you tell me what is happening here ?

Comment: Did u just add a lambda ?

Comment: Yes, Lambda is just shorthand for a function, so using { return } is also correct

Comment: Ah ok I was confused with `(_)`. Could you tell me what that does

Comment: Ok, sorry, that is just a way to there is one argument but I am not going to use it (or care about it). You can call it whatever you want but it does seem to be a unwritten convention

Comment: With Dart, as you may know is that it is optionally/implied typed so you don't have to specify the type. you could also say `(context) => new Text)'...'`

Answer (score 1):

The **child** deprecated. If you look the this property, you can this warning.

> Instead of using the "child" argument, return the child from a closure provided to the "builder" argument. This will ensure that the BuildContext is appropriate for widgets built in the dialog.

If you want to use **builder**, only write a function that returns your widget.

Example usage in my loader function

```
void showLoader(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => new ProgressHUD(
    color: Colors.white,
    containerColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  ));
}
```

Usage

```
// Start to show loader
showLoader(context);
// Do a async job and wait it
await do();
// Hide the loader
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can assign text widget to the *alert* variable, like this:

`var alert = new Text("Hello dialog");`

Since the *child* is deprecated:

`showDialog(context: context, child: alert);`

we can write it like this:

`showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => alert);`

If you want to create more complex dialog, you can redefine *alert* like this:

```
var alert = new AlertDialog(
    title: new Text('App'),
    content: new Text(message),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(onPressed: () {Navigator.pop(context);},
          child: new Text('OK'))
    ],
  );
```

and use it the same as above.

Comment: I this this is the solution for not deprecated but after showDialog appears the problem was the same dimmed at showDialog even using builder (_)=>alert, any idea bout this one ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Warning'),
          content: new Text('Hi this is Flutter Alert Dialog'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                })
          ],
        ));
```